# Detecting which shape/image on JPanel was clicked and setting a pointer to it for other functions to use

Tags: java, arraylist, mouselistener

I have a JPanel, on which there are drawn various shapes (rectangles, circles, images and the like), all of which inherit from "moveable" class (which holds just the coordinates of the center of the shape).
The objects are stored in arraylists and on each click, each arraylist is iterated through to check whether a shape has been clicked or not.

Now, what I would like to do is have a pointer of type "moveable" which points at whatever the clicked shape is, so that when I set it in MousePressed function, I can still use it e.g. in MouseDragged function to drag the image around.

I was able to simulate that behaviour by using a temporary value, performing operations on it and replacing the original object with the modified one, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If your pointer is also a Shape, there is no other way then to create a new one.
Shapes in Java are bound to a location, and cannot be moved.

If it isn't a Shape, then you have various ways to do it properly,
just store the new location somewhere and draw the pointer there.
This would work with an image, or a Shape directly drawn through the Graphics-Object:

```
g.drawImage(pointerImage, pointerX, pointerY, null);
```

or

```
g.fillRectangle(pointerX, pointerY, width, height, null);
//or any other "g.fill..."-method;
```